# Difference between voltage measuring from induction motor junction box and VFD output terminal

Tags: signal-processing, induction-motor, vfd

I want to measure stator voltage of VFD fed induction motor. It's common to measure from juction box, which should be the exact stator voltage of induction motor, but I wonder if it's possible to measure the voltage from VFD output terminal. What's the difference between the voltage from VFD output terminal and from motor junction box? Is the motor junction box voltage merely a filtered version of VFD terminal voltage?

Answer (score 0):

The VFD output terminals U, V & W and the motor terminals U, V & W are inter-connected.

Measurement at either location wouldn't make any difference.

[image]

Comment: So they are all PWM voltages with plenty of harmonics?

Comment: Yes, but the output voltage of a VFD can be measured accurately with an analog meter.